# HTML coding a newsletter

Tags: email, html-email, mailchimp, photoshop

I'm an absolute - and I mean absolute - beginner with code. I understand a lot about graphic design and how digital design works, but this doesn't help much!

I want to use Mailchimp to send out a newsletter for a client, who has a specific brand design identity. Unlike other drag-and-drop email services (such as the Squarespace newsletter add on) there is little I can do to customise the email design.

One way I've been told to do this is to use Photoshop to design the email content (layout, text etc) and import as images into the Mailchimp template. I have reservations about building an email from images though, as the images won't be responsive and work well on mobiles. It also means I can't use hyperlinks from specific text.

So I've considered coding my own using HTML... but baffled where to start? And whether it's a good idea at all? While there's a lot Mailchimp can do to keep a newsletter looking on-brand, the main thing I'd want to incorporate is a specific font.

Two questions:

> Is it a good idea for a newbie to attempt to HTML code an email?
>   If not, how else could I work with Mailchimp to customise as much as possible?
>
> If it is 'doable', where can I go about learning the process? Resources, tutorials?

Comment: *Is it a good idea for a newbie to attempt x* – duh! If you're motivated, go for it. That's how you'll learn it.

Comment: When you're coming from design, you might want to try out [WebFlow](https://webflow.com). As far as I've seen it, it allows you to visually build HTML using drag'n'drop. You still need to learn how the views in HTML are arranged and stuff, but this would take the syntax out of your learning curve. *Disclaimer:* I am NOT connected to WebFlow in any way.

Comment: Right, but I know it's not something I'll take to easily. Okay thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Responsive e-mail design is one of the most complicated HTML tasks in my opinion, if I were you I would start from some nice existing templates:

https://litmus.com/community/templates

And read up about some [responsive email tips](https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/responsive-email/).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise there were customisable templates around the internet!

Comment: @molly there are lots. You can find some on GitHub as well. There is one done by Ted Goas that is pretty good as well.